# Get most recent tag on a commit

Tags: git, git-tag

I have a work flow where i want to use git tags to push releases though my pipeline.

```
git init
touch readme.md
git add .
git commit -m "com1"
git tag -a 1.0.0-rc.1 -m "t1"

touch xxx
git add .
git commit -m "com2"
git tag -a 1.0.0-alpha1 -m "t2"
git tag -a 1.0.0-rc1 -m "t2"
git tag -a 1.0.0 -m "r1"
```

My log looks like:

```
commit 132fa7712234e0ea0ee72b55123d9fbfd7dbe75a (HEAD -> master, tag: 1.0.0-alpha1, tag: 1.0.0-rc1, tag: 1.0.0)
Author: Ryan 
Date:   Mon Nov 26 11:08:21 2018 +0000

com2

commit 97c10b1c203bc34f1234ba38e214c9f72cc4a03a (tag: 1.0.0-rc.1)
Author: Ryan 
Date:   Mon Nov 26 11:07:43 2018 +0000

com1
```

How can I ensure that only the most recent tag is returned?

Comment: What is your definition of "most recent tag"?

Comment: In this case, 1.0.0 would be the most recent as it was committed last.
Basically I want the tag that was added last on head

Comment: AFAIU the question is about `git log` decorations: `(HEAD -> master, tag: 1.0.0-rc.2, tag: 1.0.0)`. @Ryan wants to see `(HEAD -> master, tag: 1.0.0)`. I don't think it's possible with `git log`.

Comment: I use `git name-rev --name-only --tags --no-undefined HEAD 2>/dev/null` but it is returning the alpha tag which is the 1st one added in that last commit.

Comment: @phd Wouldn't `--decorate=full` do the job for git log output?

Comment: sorry `git log` was just to show that there were multiple tags on the commit. 

All i need to do is ensure I pull back the most recent tag on a commit if there are multiple.

As I said I was using `git name-rev --name-only --tags --no-undefined HEAD` but it was returning the `alpha` tag and not the latest. 

It does look like `git describe` will do what I want, my issue with it was simply that it will return `1.0.0-#-g#######" even if no tag is on that commit. 

I may just have to parse out some of the oddness with a `egrep -v "-\d+-g[0-9a-z]{7}` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git describe <commit ID>
```

does the job.

It returns the most recent tag reachable by this commit, then if the tag is not on the commit itself, appends a description of said commit (# of commits "away" + tagged commit ID)

See the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) for the options and details.

Alternatively, if as comments suggest you seek to make this info appear in the output of git log, try the option `--decorate=full`

Comment: I think this will work well enough, I only didnt consider it because it will return `<lastTag>-#-g#######` even if no tag is applied to that commit (when one has been used in a prior commit).

I was ideally looking for: `if tagged -> showLatestTag else git describe`